# Elegant way to excecute many alarm clocks?

Tags: c++, clock

Let's say I have a vector of exact future times of multiple events.  I want those events to launch when their respective times have been reached. How do I do this without constantly using if statements to check that the current time is one of those set times?  This constant checking, especially if many other things are running in my program (and some of those times may be a bit away from now) will reduce the performance of my program. I'm using c++11, latest version of GCC.

Comment: priority queue comes to mind

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++11, it's probably easiest to create a thread, have it sleep until the next alarm time. The most efficient way to store the times for the alarms is probably a priority queue.

If you don't have C++ 11 available, you might consider Boost Threads instead. The standard's threads are based closely on Boost threads, so using them will be fairly similar.

If you don't want to use that, you'll pretty much need to use operating system facilities to do the job. With almost any reasonably modern OS, you can create a thread and have it sleep until the next alarm time, but you'll probably also have something that supports what you want a little more directly (call a function at a specified time). The details of that will be specific to the OS though.